# IF(ISNA(MATCH function not pulling data properly

Tags: excel, vlookup

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kTkfd.png)[image]

I am using

```
=IF(ISNA(MATCH(H40,$A$3:$A$146,0)),””,VLOOKUP(H40,$A$3:$B$146,2,FALSE))
```

It is not pulling all the data from the cell. Can anyone suggest the reason why?

Comment: Unclear...........is it pulling the **wrong value** or is it giving an **error** ???

Comment: Is your code in the Worksheet using the curly-quotes (`”`) exactly as typed in this post, or straight-quotes (`"`)?  (Also, would `IFERROR` make your code simpler?)

Comment: Help us help you - provide a screenshot of your dataset, the result of your formula and the expected value.

Comment: From the looks of what you have it seems the reason it wouldn't pull anything is `H40`'s match with `A3:A146` is `#N/A`. First, try the `vlookup` without the `IF` statement so you can see if the issue is happened there or whether it's on your condition.

Comment: just added image

Comment: @user5540208 Your image appears to be suffering from Pixel Deficiency - so I am unable to see the answer to my earlier question.  Do you have one which hasn't shrunk in the wash?

Comment: try to use iferror() wrap around index match formula instead. ref : https://exceljet.net/index-and-match